# Compare user input with a list in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I'm trying to compare 2 elements : one is a user input and the other is an element from a list.
The fact is that when the user enter a value that is in the list, the program print "Ok". But since there's two type of element in my list (integer and string), the user can only compare his value with every string of the list...

```
list = ["test", "testOne", 5, 10]
continuer = True

while continuer:
    word = input("Enter a word : ")
    for elements in list:
        if word in list:
            print("Ok")
            break
        else:
            print("Not ok")
            break
```

I really need these numbers to be integers, can you give me some advices ?
Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

You can add something like this:

```
word = input("Enter a word : ")
try:
    word = int(word)
except ValueError:
    print("Values is not int")
```

Answer (score 1):

- Avoid using `list` as a variable name
- Use string data in your list
- Use `in` to check element presence in your list

Code:

```
lst = ['test', 'testOne', '5', '10']
word = input('Enter a word : ')
if word in lst:
    print('OK')
else:
    print('Not OK')
```

Answer (score 0):

To check user input value for each of the elements from a list containing both String and Integer type data, we can use a `try`-`except` block.

- At first, we will check if the user input and list item contain integer data in a `try` block. If the data matches, we will print `Ok` to the user.
- If the above `try` block throws an exception, we will verify if both values are matched. If the data matches, we will print `Ok` to the user.

If none of the above cases are affirmative for all the items on the list, we will print `Not ok` to the user.

```
data = ["test", "testOne", 5, 10]

while True:
      word = input("Enter a word : ")
      if word == "exit":
            break
      word_found = False
      for element in data:
            try:
                  if int(word) == int(element):
                        word_found = True
                        break
            except ValueError:
                  if word == element:
                        word_found = True
                        break
      if word_found:
            print("Ok")
      else:
            print("Not ok")
```

Output:

```
Enter a word : Shovon
Not ok
Enter a word : test
Ok
Enter a word : 34
Not ok
Enter a word : 5
Ok
Enter a word : Ahmedur
Not ok
Enter a word : testOne
Ok
Enter a word : exit
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You don't need to iterate through the list using for loop as you can check existence of an element using "in" operator
   So

```
    if word in list:
         print("OK")
```

is sufficient.

2. If you want to ensure only integer is entered, just validate the user input like int(word)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answer guys !
I tried it in another way

```
list = ["test", "testOne", 5, 10]
continuer = True


def safe_cast(val, to_type, default=None):
    try:
        return to_type(val)
    except (ValueError, TypeError):
        return default

while continuer:
    word = input("Enter a word : ")
    for element in list:
        if isinstance(element, str) and element == word:
            print("Ok")
            break
        elif isinstance(element, int) and safe_cast(word, int, 0) == element:
            print("ok")
            break
```

And it worked well ! Sorry for the inconvenience

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
    list = ["test", "testOne", 5, 10]
    continuer = True
    getlist1=str(list)  #Converting all the elements in list to string
    while continuer:
        word = input("Enter a word : ")            
        for elements in list:
            if ((word) in (getlist1)):
                print("Ok")
                break
            else:
                print("Not ok")
                break
```

Output:
Enter a word : 5

Ok

Enter a word : 10

Ok

Enter a word : test

Ok

Enter a word : testOne

Ok

Enter a word : hello

Not ok